# PHP Web Scraping And JSON or Array Output

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping

I'm experimenting scraping Amazon with PHP but I don't know what I am doing wrong. The problem is that I can't access all the data I scraped. Here is my code:

```
<?php

  $url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_9?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=most+sold+items+on+amazon&sprefix=most+sold%2Caps%2C435&crid=348CE8G406XVG&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Amost+sold+items+on+amazon';

  $html = file_get_html($url);

  foreach ($html->find('h2[class=a-size-medium]') as $element) {

    echo "<li>" .$element->plaintext."</li><br>";       

  } 
?>
```

The foreach statement loops through and output the plain text but I want to be able to pass the plain text to a variable or array. The problem is that if I do that and output the result, I only get the last string of the plain text array. I have done lots of research to find what I'm doing wrong but I can't find it. Please any help will be appreciated. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<?php
  $url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_9?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=most+sold+items+on+amazon&sprefix=most+sold%2Caps%2C435&crid=348CE8G406XVG&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Amost+sold+items+on+amazon';
  $hold = array();
  $html = file_get_html($url);

  foreach ($html->find('h2[class=a-size-medium]') as $element) {

    $hold = $element->plaintext;        

  } 
  print_r($hold);

?>
```

The second code will output the last string of the plain text which is: "Rubbermaid LunchBlox Side Container Kit, 2-Pack, 1806176". I also tried achieving this by encoding and decoding the plain text but nothing changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I feel PHP may not be the best language to do this with...

Comment: @RoshanBhumbra;  Thanks for commenting. Can you explain why?

Comment: Php is more suited for serving pages than scraping them and has various quirks that make it less good for extended operation. For example it has an execution time limit so you can't leave it continuously scraping pages like you an with many other languages.

Comment: @roshanbhumbra ini_set('max_execution_time', -1); "The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed." PHP is perfect for scraping.

Comment: that being said, amazon is perfect for api - not scraping, imho; but, for all we know, this is a weekend shopping project, in which case, scraping makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the array hold to a string...add new elements to the array:

```
$hold[] = $element->plaintext;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why did you downgraded the question? I already reformatted it. I didn't remember to use backtics. Anyway, thanks for commenting.

Comment: it wasn't me my friend

Comment: Ok. thanks. I noticed I was missing declaring $hold as array. Your contribution made the fix. Thanks once again.

Comment: no worries, for fun, you don't have to declare arrays in php.  you could take that out, and while less clear for other programmers, it would function identically.  fwiw.